# $a < b$ iff $S(a) \leq b$

Tags: inequality, peano-axioms, natural-numbers

I want to prove $a < b$ iff $S(a) \leq b$ but I can't figure it out for the life of me, how to even begin.

$S(a)$ is the successor of $a$ and $a < b$ is defined as $a \leq b$ with $a \neq b$. And then $a \leq b$ is defined as $b = a + d$ for some $d$ (all numbers here are natural numbers).

Since it is an iff statement I need to prove both:

$a < b \implies S(a) \leq b$

and

$S(a) \leq b \implies a < b$.

But I don't see any clear method of attack. At first I tried induction on $a$ to prove $a < b \implies S(a) \leq b$ but then the inductive step adds one to $a$ so it may no longer be true that $S(a) < b$.

So I tried inducting on $b$ instead but if we start from $0$ then $a < 0$ is always false since $0 = a + j \implies a=0, j=0$, but $a = j = 0$ isn't allowed.

I'm hopelessly stuck. :(

Comment: All the proofs so far are hiding something, either using unproven things or just reducing it to things that are are hard as the original. Just do it by induction. $0<1$ implies $S(0)=1\leq 1$. Now assume $a<b$ implies $S(a)\leq b$. Then it is clear that $a<S(b)$ implies $S(a)\leq b\leq S(b)$. Now, if $a+1<b$, then there is $b'$ such that $S(b')=b$. Therefore, $S(a)<S(b')$. Hence $a\leq b'$ and $a\neq b'$. Therefore $S(a)< b'$. Therefore $S(S(a))<S(b')=b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is more direct than José's proposal:

Suppose that $a<b$, which is to say $a\le b$ and $a\ne b$. We have $a+d=b$ for some $d$, and we can't have $d=0$ because then $a=b$, which would be a contradiction. So $d=Se$ for some $e$ and then $a+Se=b$ implies $Sa+e=b$ by standard properties of addition. Thus $Sa\le b$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $S(a) \le b$; then $a \le S(a)$ also, so by transitivity of $\le$, we have $a \le b$.  But if $a = b$, then we would have $S(a) \le a$.  We now have to prove this is a contradiction.

To see this, we prove by induction on $a$ that for all $a$, $S(a) \not\le a$.  For the base case $a=0$, if $1 \le 0$, then there would be some $n$ such that $1+n = 0$.  But then $S(n) = 1+n = 0$, which contradicts one of the Peano axioms.  For the inductive case, suppose $S(a) \not\le a$; we need to prove $S(S(a)) \not\le S(a)$.  Suppose to the contrary that we had $S(S(a)) \le S(a)$.  Then for some $n$, $S(S(a)) + n = S(a) = S(S(a) + n)$.  Therefore, $S(a) + n = a$, so $S(a) \le a$, contradicting the inductive hypothesis.

---

Now, for the converse, we will start out with a lemma: for all $a, b$, either $S(a) \le b$, $S(b) \le a$, or $a=b$.  We prove by induction on $a$ that for all $b$, this disjunction happens.  For the base case $a$, I will leave it as an exercise to prove by induction on $b$ that for all $b$, either $b=0$ or $b = S(b')$ for some $b'$; in the latter case, then $S(0) = 1 \le b$.  For the inductive case, fix $a$, and suppose we know that for all $b$, the disjunction happens.  Then we need to prove the same thing for $S(a)$.  So, for any $b$, we know that either $b=0$ or $b=S(b')$ for some $b$.  In the first case, then $S(b) \le S(a)$.  In the second case, we either have $S(a) \le b'$, in which case $S(S(a)) \le S(b') = b$; or $a = b'$, in which case $S(a) = S(b') = b$; or $S(b') \le a$, in which case $S(b) = S(S(b')) \le S(a)$.

Now that we've established this lemma, suppose that $a < b$.  Then by the previous paragraph, we know that either $S(a) \le b$, $a = b$, or $S(b) \le a$.  However, the case $a = b$ contradicts the assumption that $a < b$.  Similarly, if $S(b) \le a$, then by the assumption that $a \le b$, we know $S(a) \le S(b)$.  By transitivity of $\le$, this would imply $S(a) \le a$, which contradicts what we established above.  Therefore, the only remaining possibility is that $S(a) \le b$.

---

(While I was writing this, Henning Makholm's answer gave a much more succinct argument for the $a < b \implies S(a) \le b$ part.  I still think the first part of my argument would be useful for pointing out a subtlety which needs to be addressed in the $S(a) \le b \implies a < b$ part.)

Comment: His answer is not better than yours. The length of the induction is being hidden in the proof that sum is associative, which is what he used.

Comment: @saltandpepper Well, to use a programming analogy, I still like clearer factorization of code, even if it doesn't result in a "run time" improvement.

Comment: @saltandpepper: Actually I'm only using that addition is _commutative_, plus the recursion equation for addition: $a+Se=S(a+e)=S(e+a)=e+Sa=Sa+e$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Doesn't change the fact that if you want to complete the argument you will get a proof as long as this.

Comment: It's also not too hard to prove directly by induction that $a+Se = Sa+e$, and in fact, IIRC that's used as a step in the proof that addition is commutative.

Comment: I also happen to have used associativity of addition, as a step in the proof that $\le$ is transitive.

Answer (score 0):

If $S(a)\leqslant b$ then, since $a<S(a)$, $a<b$.

On the other hand, suppose that $a<b$. Then there is some $k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $a+k=b$ and, since $k\neq0$, $k=S(k')$ for some $k'\in\mathbb N$. But\begin{align}a+k=b&\iff a+S(k')=b\\&\iff S(a)+k'=b\\&\iff S(a)\leqslant b.\end{align}

Comment: Good job using what you wanted to prove to prove it.

Comment: @saltandpepper Where did I do that?

Comment: You were trying to prove that $a<b$ implies $S(a)\leq b$ and you get a contradiction with "since $S(a)\leq b$", and then conclude that $S(a)\leq b$.

Comment: @saltandpepper I've edited my answer. Thank you. Perhaps that you might explain why you decided to make me notice that I made an error in such an unkind sort of way.

Comment: Isn't $m<n \implies S(m) \le n$ just the same thing as what you wanted to prove, still?

Comment: What is inside parentheses is what you are proving. I don't know why it needs to be there anyway. Every body knows that it is easy, which makes even more funny the circularity in the first attempt (Strictly speaking you haven't proved that you can't have $a<b<S(a)$, which is pretty much the same that needs to be proven.) and the gap still remaining.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Right. Thank you. I hope that it is correct now,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just *giving* a proof, like all earlier answers seem to do, let me try to show you how you could *find* a proof, like you asked.

I will be using a 'logical' and 'calculational' approach that may be more formal than you are used to, but which often helps me.  (You can find background information in, e.g., [EWD1300](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html).)$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
%$

After expanding the definitions of $\;<\;$ and $\;\le\;$, you are asked to prove, for every $\;a,b\;,$
$$
\tag{0}
\langle \exists d :: d + a = b \rangle \;\land\; a \not= b \;\equiv\; \langle \exists d :: d + S(a) = b \rangle
$$
Looking at the shape of these formulas, it seems the best approach to start with the right hand side, and rewrite it working towards the LHS's $\;\langle \exists d :: d + a = b \rangle\;$.

Below is the most straightforward way I could find for that.

---

For every $\;a,b\;$,

$$\calc
    \tag{RHS}
    \langle \exists d :: d + S(a) = b \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{arithmetic, see below -- working towards $\;\ldots + a = b\;$}
    \langle \exists d :: S(d) + a = b \rangle
\op\equiv\hints{logic: introduce abbreviation $\;e := S(d)\;$, i.e., the one-point rule}\hint{in reverse -- still working towards $\;\ldots + a = b\;$} 
    \langle \exists d,e :: e = S(d) \;\land\; e + a = b \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{logic: bring all $\;d\;$'s together -- to simplify}
    \langle \exists e :: \langle \exists d :: e = S(d) \rangle \;\land\; e + a = b \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{every $\;e\;$ is either $\;0\;$ or $\;S(\ldots)\;$, i.e., $\Ref{1}$ -- to simplify}
    \langle \exists e :: e \not= 0 \;\land\; e + a = b \rangle
\op\equiv\hints{arithmetic: add $\;a\;$ to both sides of left part; use right part in left}\hint{-- to remove the $\;e\;$ from the left part}
    \langle \exists e :: b \not= a \;\land\; e + a = b \rangle
\op\equiv\hints{logic: extract part not using $\;e\;$ out of $\;\exists e\;$}\hint{-- to reach our goal}
    \langle \exists e :: e + a = b \rangle \;\land\; a \not= b
    \tag{LHS}
\endcalc$$

---

Note how this proof is completely 'driven' by our goal (the LHS), and by the desire to simplify.

Also note that apart from the usual rules of arithmetic ($\;+\;$ is symmetrical with identity $\;0\;$, and $\;S(a)+b = S(a+b)\;$), this proof makes clear that the only more advanced rule we used is that our domain consists of $\;0\;$ and successors: for all $\;a\;$,
$$
\tag{1}
a = 0 \;\not\equiv\; \langle \exists b :: a = S(b) \rangle
$$

Finally, note how both directions are proved together: there was no need to have separate $\;\then\;$ and $\;\when\;$ proofs.

$%
\endgroup
%$